# Change the SharePoint 2013 default radio button and check box color

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, css, branding

I am wondering is this possible to change the SharePoint default radio button and check box color?

Please suggest me some best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not, sure it's possible, and you only need CSS3 to do so. As it's a question of personal flavor which style you'd prefer, it's hard to give suggestions, so please give some further details about your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I mean I like to change the radio buttons and check box color in survey list. (Quesform.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `radio/checkbox` button is `input` control with `radio` and `checkbox` type, so try to do the following:

- Create a CSS file,
- Add the below CSS

**Style:**

```
input[type="radio"] 
{
    background: red !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    background: red !important;
}
```

- Upload the CSS file to style library.
- Open Site > Site Settings.
- Below Look and Feel > Click on (Master Page) or Design Manager.
- At Site Master Page Settings > Scroll down till `Alternate CSS URL`
- Check `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:`
- Browse to your CSS file
- Check  `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL`  if you need to apply CSS for all subsites.

[image]

**[Update]**

The above steps applied for all input control with radio/checkbox in your site.

But based on your above comment, you need it in `survey list. (Quesform.aspx)`

So do the following:

- Edit your quest form.
- Add script editor web part.
- Add the below style

**Style**

```
<style>
input[type="radio"] 
{
    background: red !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] 
{
    background: red !important;
}
</style>
```

- Save your page.

**OutPut**

[image]